# how to get text value between the end of </h3> and <br/>

Tags: python, text, screen-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to doing screen scraping using python and beautiuflsoup. I met one problem is that I dont know how to get the text value before `<br/>`

Here is one example:

```
<h3>
    Francois  Abboud
</h3>
Professor,&nbsp;
Internal Medicine
<br />
<br />
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `.next_sibling`:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html = """
... <h3>
...     Francois  Abboud
... </h3>
... Professor,&nbsp;
... Internal Medicine
... <br />
... <br />
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> 
>>> for h3 in soup.findAll("h3"):
...     print 'h3:'
...     print repr(h3)
...     print 'next sibling:'
...     print repr(h3.next_sibling)
... 
h3:
<h3>
    Francois  Abboud
</h3>
next sibling:
u'\nProfessor,\xa0\nInternal Medicine\n'
```

I should say that I didn't know how to do this two minutes ago, but I knew about `findAll`.  So I got one of the `h3` objects and I used IPython's tab completion to see what lived inside it, and it had things like `h3.next_element` and `h3.next_sibling` and I tried them until one worked.

Comment: It sounds right. However, I get result like this:Francois
Abboud

h3:
<h3>
        
        Francois  Abboud
       </h3>
next sibling:
None

Comment: @user1652287: then there's probably some difference between the data that I used above and your HTML.  If you run exactly my code -- just remove the ">>> " and the "... " -- do you get what I do?

Comment: Yeah, I did, the result is 'none'. is there any method also?

Answer (score 0):

tsup, if you assign that html to a string value like so:

```
html = 'your html here'
```

then you could do a split on it and the string will be split into an array of string values holding strings on either side of the delimeter you specify:

```
def extractmyCrap(html):
   h3splitStrings = html.split('</h3>')
   h3splitStrings = h3splitStrings[1]
   extractedText = h3splitStrings.split('<br/>')
   return extractedText[0]
```

Please comment if you need any durther help, or if i understood your question incorrectly

Comment: Hi, the thing I want to do is getting text before <br/>. For example, in the html there are multiple h3, h4, h2. and there is always one <br/> come after it. So how I can find the value between h3 and br, h4 and br ...